# Running Zeppelin with https using Nginx context routing

Tags: nginx, apache-zeppelin

I have a requirement to run the services (Zeppelin, grafana etc) using https. I have installed certificates and added below configuration to NGINX.

But still it is not working, please let me know if any other configuration to be added. Thanks!

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl;

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate        ../crt/*****.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    ../crt/*****.key;
        .
        .
        .
        location /zeppelin {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/;
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you change 'proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/;' to 'proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;' and try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Configure the zeppelin IP in `upstream` and use the upstream name in `proxy_pass` like below

> ```
> upstream zeppelin {
>   server 127.0.0.1:8080;
> }
> server {
>   ....
>   location / {
>     proxy_pass http://zeppelin;
>   }
>   ....
> }
> ```

2. To host zeppelin under 'zeppelin' context you have to change the `zeppelin.server.context.path` property in conf/zeppelin-site.xml
3. Configuring zeppelin using nginx needs more configuration like websocket proxying. You can refer the sample nginx configuration in this [link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/security/authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Could you let me know how to setup the reverse proxy for Yarn UI as well.